# SVN authz using linux group

Tags: linux, svn, authorization, authz, svn-administraton

Is it possible to setup an SVN authz file to use linux server groups?

To try to give a bit more detail/an example, say I have and SVN authz file as follows:

```
[groups]
developers = linuxUserA, linuxUserB
reviewers = linuxUserC
endUsers = linuxGroupA  <- can I insert a Linux group here

[/project]
@developers = rw
@reviewers = r

[/project/downloads/]
@endUsers = r
```

userA, userB and userC all exist as Linux users, and are granted access as expected.  However, members of linuxGroupA don't seem to be granted access (in this example to the downloads folder).

So, can the svn authz be configured to refer to a linux group, whose members will get access (to say the downloads folder above)?

Answer (score 0):

**No**

Right side inside [groups] section is **always list of authz-file's objects** (another groups, aliases, users)

You can build string `endUsers = ...` by processing /etc/group and outputting linuxGroupA's final users into authz file